# Geospatially match cells of different rasters - possible?

Tags: arcgis-desktop, arcgis-10.1, raster, resolution

I have 2 rasters that were originally vector polygons. Raster2 was created from a selection of raster1. After converting both to raster, their cells don't match up (i.e. attribute info for each cell of raster1 doesn't match up with the coinciding cell for raster2). I want to be able to select a cell in raster1 with the value of 3 and know raster2's cell with the value of 3 is in the same location. Is there a way to match them?

Note: both have the same cell size.

Answer (score 1):

Try to use Spatial Analyst Tool > Extraction > Extract by Mask.

> Extracts the cells of a raster that correspond to the areas defined by a mask.

In your case, input raster would be Raster2 and feature mask data would be Raster1.